# Vue router - When replacing route view renders on top of another

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

When trying to replace the current `/login` route with another route, it seems that the new route gets rendered on top of the last, making it behave strange.

**`router.js`**

```
const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Main Page',
      component: MainPage,
      redirect: 'front-page',
      children: [
        {
          path: 'front-page',
          name: 'Front page',
          component: FrontPage,
          meta: {
            requireAuth: true,
          },
        },
        {
          path: 'home',
          name: 'Home page',
          component: HomePage,
          meta: {
            requireAuth: true,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      path: '/profile',
      name: 'Profile page',
      component: UserProfilePage,
      meta: {
        requireAuth: true,
      },
    },
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'Login page',
      component: LoginPage,
      meta: {
        requireAuth: false,
      },
    },
    {
      path: '/register',
      name: 'Registration page',
      component: RegistrationPage,
      meta: {
        requireAuth: false,
      },
    },
  ],
});
```

**`login.vue`**

```
result() {
  if (this.loginQuery.sessionToken) {
    this.setAuthToken(this.loginQuery.sessionToken);
    this.$router.replace('/front-page');
  }
},
```

Comment: Are you using navigation guards ? https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards With the "next" function you can be sure of which route you are resolving and avoid "overlapping routes" and "bottleneck route".

Comment: Yeah I have tried that but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may come from redirection,It's no necessary to set 'home' as a default route by using redirect,try code below:

```
const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      name: 'Main Page',
      component: MainPage,
      children: [
        {
          path: '/front-page',
          name: 'Front page',
          component: FrontPage,
          meta: {
            requireAuth: true,
          },
        },
        {
          path: '/',
          name: 'Home page',
          component: HomePage,
          meta: {
            requireAuth: true,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      path: '/profile',
      name: 'Profile page',
      component: UserProfilePage,
      meta: {
        requireAuth: true,
      },
    },
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'Login page',
      component: LoginPage,
      meta: {
        requireAuth: false,
      },
    },
    {
      path: '/register',
      name: 'Registration page',
      component: RegistrationPage,
      meta: {
        requireAuth: false,
      },
    },
  ],
});
```